# PHP: index.php posts headers are not clickable, not able to click inside post through header

Tags: php, post, view, posts, base-url

Good evening my fellow coders, I came here with a quest to find an answer for my  whole day solution looking problem.

Why this code

```
<h1><a href="<?=BASE_URL?>post/view/<?=$post['post_id']?>"><?=$post["post_subject"]?></a></h1>
```

is not making my post headings  link-able (aka if you click on the title, it should redirect inside of the post).

I did made function in post.php, where

```
function view(){
    $this->post = get_first("SELECT * FROM post NATURAL JOIN user WHERE post_id='$post_id'");
}
```

My github for the project is [Here](http://github.com/labkitty/blog)

Thank you for your time reading this :)) I can't find the solution on my own anymore, I hope you php gods now better than me.

Update.
It was not unclear. I asked simply fair question. Why is H1 not making post TITLE clickable, where there is a href= inside.

```
<div class="span8">
<h1><a href="<?=BASE_URL?>post/view/<?=$post['post_id']?>"><?=$post["post_subject"]?></a></h1>
    <p><?=$post["post_text"]?></p>
    <div>
        <span class="badge badge-success"><?=$post["post_created"]?></span><div class="pull-right"><span class="label">alice</span> <span class="label">story</span> <span class="label">blog</span> <span class="label">personal</span></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

All I did was made a copy of post_index.php into posts_view.php that allows me to click on title and see the post inside.

```
<?foreach( $posts as $post ):?>
<div class="span8">
    <h1><?=$post["post_subject"]?></h1>
    <p><?=$post["post_text"]?></p>
    <div>
        <span class="badge badge-success"><?=$post["post_created"]?></span><div class="pull-right"><span class="label">alice</span> <span class="label">story</span> <span class="label">blog</span> <span class="label">personal</span></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

after

```
<div class="span8">
<h1><a href="<?=BASE_URL?>post/view/<?=$post['post_id']?>"><?=$post["post_subject"]?></a></h1>
    <p><?=$post["post_text"]?></p>
    <div>
        <span class="badge badge-success"><?=$post["post_created"]?></span><div class="pull-right"><span class="label">alice</span> <span class="label">story</span> <span class="label">blog</span> <span class="label">personal</span></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I changed `<h1><?=$post["post_subject"]?></h1>` to `<h1><a href="<?=BASE_URL?>post/view/<?=$post['post_id']?>"><?=$post["post_subject"]?></a></h1>` but there is a problem, it doesnt make the `h1` clickable, but I have `a href`.

Comment: Are you sure it's a php problem, what does the generated html look like?

Comment: You should post the generated html, the (relevant section of the...) source of what you see in browser.

Comment: Do you have php short tags turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I found my own solution for my own question.

In fact. I had to put`<h1><a href="<?=BASE_URL?>post/view/<?=$post['post_id']?>"><?=$post["post_subject"]?></a></h1>`  into post_index.php  not post_view.php.